# Javascript Observable performance issue

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

**Current Working Code**

I have the following [`rxjs/Observable`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html):

```
findMessages(chatItem: any): Observable<any[]> {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        let processing: boolean = false;
        this.firebaseDataService.findMessages(chatItem).forEach(firebaseItems => {
            if (!processing) {
                processing = true;
                this.localDataService.findMessages(chatItem).then((localItems: any[]) => {
                    let mergedItems: any[] = this.arrayUnique(firebaseItems.concat(localItems), false);
                    mergedItems.sort((a, b) => {
                        return parseFloat(a.negativtimestamp) - parseFloat(b.negativtimestamp);
                    });
                    if (this.me && mergedItems && mergedItems[0] && this.me.uid === mergedItems[0].memberId2) {
                        this.updateChatWithMessage(chatItem, mergedItems[0], false);
                    }
                    observer.next(mergedItems);
                    processing = false;
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

and

```
this.firelist = this.dataService.findMessages(this.chatItem);
this.firelist.subscribe(items => {
    ...
});
```

As you can see, it returns a list of `firebaseItems` and `localItems`, which are merged to `mergedItems`. This works perfectly.

**Performance Enhancement**

However, I am trying to increase the performance that the items load. So figure, I would like to first load the `localItems`, and then add to the list with the `firebaseItems`.

So I try add the following function:

```
findLocalMessages(chatItem: any): Observable<any[]> {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        this.localDataService.findMessages(chatItem).then((localItems: any[]) => {
            localItems.sort((a, b) => {
                return parseFloat(a.negativtimestamp) - parseFloat(b.negativtimestamp);
            });
            observer.next(localItems);
        });
    });
}
```

and call it as follows:

```
this.firelist = this.dataService.findLocalMessages(this.chatItem);
this.firelist = this.dataService.findMessages(this.chatItem);
this.firelist.subscribe(items => {
    ...
});
```

**Problem**

This has now introduced a bug, that there are now 2 `Observables` and the results are not as expected. The sort order is incorrect, and some of the items are not being added to the `this.firelist` for some reason.

**Question**

Whats the best way to handle this?

I was thinking if it's possible to make the `findLocalMessages` `Observable` only get fired once, and then it never works again, as the `findMessages` `Observable` will maintain the list. Is this possible? I have been looking at the `Observable` api, and can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Its `rxjs`. Sorry, I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the risk of oversimplifying the problem statement, you have two streams of data that you want to merge and sort in an efficient manner.

The separation you have made is a step in the right direction.
The reason why you are not getting all the messages is that you are overriding the first observable with the second.Have a look at the following example and see what happens if you try and assign the second observable to move instead of move2.

```js
 let move = Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById("1"), 'mousemove');
 let move2 = Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById("2"), 'mousemove');
      move
          .subscribe((event:any) => {
              if (event) {
                console.log(event.path[0].id)
              }
          });

          move2
          .subscribe((event:any) => {
              if (event) {
                console.log(event.path[0].id)
              }
          });
```

```html
<h1>
  <div id="1">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>

  <div id="2">
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  </div>
</h1>
```

In order to merge the two streams together properly you need to use the [merge operator](http://rxmarbles.com/#merge) as shown below:

```js
let move = Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById("1"), 'mousemove');
let move2 = Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById("2"), 'mousemove');
      move.merge(move2)
          .subscribe((event:any) => {
              if (event) {
                console.log(event.path[0].id)
              }
          });
```

Now all you need to do is sort them. I would advice that you do the sort only after the merge because otherwise, you will end up with two streams that are sorted locally, not globally.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is more simple, but better. That works for me.